# Pick out certain part of NSMutableAray

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsstring, split, nsmutablearray

How would I pick out certain part of NSMutableArray?
One fielding array from server is 2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles 
I am trying to get just the time.
I was thinking turning it into a string and then getting it and then back into NSMutablearray to populate to tableview cells. 
I am still looking at documentation

Options I am thinking of:
-subarrayWithRange:
componentsSeparatedByString:

UPDATE:
Here is what I am doing now to get the field of appointments

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSDictionary* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
    self.timesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"allslots: %@", myslots);

    for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];

        for (myDays in slot){

        if ([[self.myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])

           [self.timesArray addObject:[self.myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];

        //NSLog(@"This is the times count: %@", timesArray.count);

    }





    }
     NSLog(@"These are the times avail: %@", self.timesArray); 
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

All I want eventually is an array of just the times. I am sorry if I am not being clear. I am trying to. Please let me know what information I can provide to paint a clearer picture

Comment: What? Are there multiple date strings in your array? Or what's that?

Comment: An NSMutableArray (or NSArray) is an ordered container for other objects. You're going to have to tell us what kind of object is actually **in** the array if you want us to tell you how to do something with its string representation. For example, if they are NSDate objects, there will be a much easier way to get just the time that doesn't involve string processing.

Comment: Array of dictionaries, each day is dictionary. Multiple time fields (appointment times) each day. 9-10, 10-11, 11-12, etc. So there are 9-1 9-10, 9-1 10-11 and so on

Comment: You should give a concrete example of your input array and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd save it as a string first

```
NSString *someString = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

and then use something like NSMakeRange to get just that bit

```
[someString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11,18)];
```

Comment: When I try this it says [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2620692019 beyond bounds for empty array'
I am working on figuring out why

Comment: Not really. You do have to declare that placeholder "index" variable I put in there though. Your index number / iteration variable should go there.

Comment: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:index]; The index goes inside the brackets as far as I know.

Comment: I am using for statements (fast enumeration) so I don't have iteration variables as far as I know

Comment: You could add an index variable and increase it manually. See this thread for additional information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113482/keep-track-of-index-in-fast-enumeration

Comment: Can we move to chat so I can explain what it is now doing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16159/discussion-between-tidev-and-suiz-uzcategui)

Comment: Thanks for taking the extra time in chat to help me out